# proper way to display day month and tody's date in php

Tags: php, html

I have the following HTML and PHP code to display Month, today's date and the day.

```
 <p class="time">
   <time class="icon">
     <strong><?php  echo date(F); ?></strong>
     <em><?php  echo date(l); ?></em>
     <span> <?php  echo date(d); ?></span>
   </time>
```

I get errors when I use the following

```
  ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Errors are:

```
  Notice: Use of undefined constant F - assumed 'F' in C:\dir\subdir\includes\header.php on line 43 January
  Notice: Use of undefined constant d ......
  Notice: Use of undefined constant l ......
```

I checked PHP data manual at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

subsequently, the examples shown on php manual website led me to added the following line to the top of my file but no change.

```
  <?php date_default_timezone_set('US/Pacific'); ?>
```

I'm still getting the error messages.  Is there something I need to be aware of.  I also tried adding the data_default_timezone_set function directly (I know it's redundant but i figured to try and see what happens).  within the html tags of course to no avail

```
  <?php date_default_timezone_set('US/Pacific'); echo date(F); ?>
  <?php date_default_timezone_set('US/Pacific'); echo date(l); ?>
  <?php date_default_timezone_set('US/Pacific'); echo date(d); ?>
```

Any thoughts?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: The notices tell you **EXACTLY** what's wrong. `F`, `l`, and `d` are **NOT** constants that have been `define()`ed. You want `date('F')`. Since this is just a simple typo, voting to close

Comment: Thank you so much Marc B.  didn't see your post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put quotes around it the string passed into the date function:

```
<strong><?php  echo date('F'); ?></strong>
<em><?php  echo date('l'); ?></em>
<span> <?php  echo date('d'); ?></span>
```

Also, in modern PHP most developers do not use the `<?php ... ?>` syntax either. Something like [Smarty](http://smarty.net) or [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io) is typically used.

In smarty it would look like this:

```
<strong>{$smarty.const.now|date_format:'%e'}</strong>
<em>{$smarty.const.now|date_format:'%A'}</em>
<span>{$smarty.const.now|date_format:'%d'}</span>
```

I'm not as familiar with Mustache, but it's fairly similar to Smarty but cross platform/cross language.

Comment: Abhi,  Thank you! that did the trick.  little details that seems to make a huge difference in how much time is spent figuring these errors out.  I need wait 5 minutes to accept your answer.  Thanks again!

Comment: Abhi,  I definitely need to look into Smarty and Mustache as I have no idea what they are. Thank you though for the suggestion/comment

Comment: @user3001162 basically the idea with smarty/mustache is you have a bunch of PHP code that runs first, preparing all the data that will be displayed, and then it passes the data on to smarty or mustache which will load a "tpl" file containing all the HTML and the provided data will be embedded in the html.

Comment: sweet! That sounds like allot of hassle-free development :) Thx allot!